# SSIS - how can I see where a connection is used?

Tags: ssis

Is there a quick way to determine where within a package a connection is used?

Answer (score 4):

within visual studio you can search for all instances of the connection string with
ctrl+shift+f

Answer (score 4):

I usual right click on the package and look through the XML code